# donloading gif giles in iphone - improving performance

Tags: ios4

I have a table view showing records 
When user taps ona  record I need to show the details of that record 
The detail shown also includes an image that I need to download from awebserver ( GIF ) file

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection release];
[request release];

NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

The problem is the last line where it takes some time to download the image

I am wondering what the possible options should be / can be done

I know the `initWithRequest` is aynchronous - but the call to `dataWithContentsofUrl` is right in the main path - so user experiences a wait time of more than a second

Is there a way that I could possibly have the `dataWithContentsofUrl` pushed into some other method that is called asynchronously

If thats possible I could look at showing a spinner or "please wait...." while the image loads

The other option I am thinking of is :
Should I have the images saved on the server in a zipped format ?
and then unzip ?
will it be faster ?
has anyone tried it before ?
or does anyone have a better option ?

I am not looking for spoon feeding but would like to hear your ideas please!